# "TypeError: draw() takes exactly 1 non-keyword argument (3 given)"

Tags: python, pyglet

I wrote this code to open a window with Pyglet in Python...

```
import pyglet
from pyglet import window

class Window(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        myLabel = pyglet.text.Label("Prototype")

        windowText = myLabel.draw(Window, "Hello World",
                        font_name = "Times New Roman",
                        font_size = 36,
                        color = (193, 205, 193, 255))

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.label.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Window()
    pyglet.app.run()
```

however every time I run it I get this error:

```
TypeError: draw() takes exactly 1 non-keyword argument (3 given)
```

AFAIK the "(3 given)" means the problem is with the font_size or color arguments but I'm not sure. Could someone explain what's wrong and help me make this work?

Answer (score 1):

The three non-keyword arguments you've given are the object instance, `Window`, and `"Hello World"`. It only expects the object instance. Check the docs again for which arguments the `draw()` method takes. Consider printing the `repr()` of `myLabel` so that you know which type it is.

Answer (score 1):

The three non-keyword arguments you're passing to draw() are myLabel (implied, becomes `self`), Window, and "Hello World".  The documentation for this method is [here](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.text.layout.TextLayout-class.html#draw).

Are you sure you didn't intend to do something more like this?

```
myLabel = pyglet.text.Label("Hello World")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used pyglet but according to the documentation [draw](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.text.layout.TextLayout-class.html#draw) does not take any parameters.

However [the constructor](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.text.Label-class.html#__init__) does take these parameters so the following would be legal:

```
label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, world',
                          font_name='Times New Roman',
                          font_size=36,
                          x=10, y=10)
```

From [here](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.text-module.html).